# Solving the following system of trigonometrical equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

> Solve the following system of equations
>   $$\begin{cases}
> \sin(a)+2\sin(a+b+c)=0 \\ 
> \sin(b)+3\sin(a+b+c)=0 \\
> \sin(c)+4\sin(a+b+c)=0
> \end{cases}$$

I added all the three equations and got $$\frac{\sin(a)+\sin(b)+\sin(c)}{9}+\sin(a+b+c)=0.$$
Then, I have very vague view on how to continue is using something like Jensen's inequality...
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @VIVID For using Jensen you need $\{a,b,c\}\subset[0,\pi]$, for example.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yes I know. So that $\sin(x)$ would be concave. Could one apply this to the question?

Comment: I think I can solve your problem for $\{a,b,c\}\subset\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$

Comment: Did you try substituting in the last equation into the previous ones? What did you get from there?

Comment: @VIVID I can prove that for $\{a,b,c\}\subset\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and unique solution it's $(0,0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

I am using that $\sin a = A \Rightarrow a = \sin^{-1} A$, which is true if they are in $[- \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

---

Let $ \sin a = A, \sin b = B, \sin c = C$.
You have shown that $ \sin (a+b+c) = -\frac{ A + B + C } { 9 } $.

Substituting back in, we get
$7A -2B - 2C = 0 $
$-3A + 6 B - 3C = 0$
$ -4 A - 4 B + 5 C = 0 $
Solutions to this system are of the form $ A:B:C = 2:3:4$.
Let $  A = 2n, B = 3n, C = 4n$ where $   -\frac{1}{4} \leq n \leq \frac{1}{4}$.

We then need to check against the condition of 
$-9\sin (a+b+c ) = A+B+C = 9n $, which gives us
$\sin^{-1} (2n) + \sin^{-1} (3n) + \sin^{-1} (4n) = - \sin^{-1}n $ or $\pi + \sin^{-1} (n) $ or $ 2\pi - \sin^{-1} (n)$.

For $n \in ( 0, \frac{1}{4})$, we can show that the LHS is $ \in (0, 3 )$, hence is never equal to the RHS. 
A similar statement holds for $ n \in ( - \frac{1}{4} , 0)$.

So, the only solution is $ n = 0 \Rightarrow A=B=C = 0  $.

---

To extend outside of the range, we need to consider $ a = \pi - \sin^{-1} A$, which makes it seem like solutions exist. To be continued (?) ...

Answer (score 0):

Expand out $\sin(a+b+c)$, take $\sin(a)=s_a$, $\cos(a)=c_a$, etc., adjoin the relations
$ s_a^2 + c_a^2 - 1 = 0$ etc, and we can solve using Groebner basis methods.
All solutions have
$\sin(a) = \sin(b) = \sin(c) = 0$, i.e. $a,b,c$ are integer multiples of $\pi$.